# With two-weapon fighting, does the second weapon get the attack roll bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e

When fighting with two weapons, one in each hand, I'm aware that your second weapon's damage roll does not get the ability score modifier (unless negative). But what about the attack roll of the second weapon?

For example: A fighter is using two light weapons. Does the second weapon get his strength modifier to the attack roll?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the Player's Basic Rules, page 74:

> You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the second attack, unless that modifier is negative.

That's the only thing it says that changes how the second attack works.  It probably doesn't need to be said, but from page 60:

> You add your Strength modifier to your attack roll and your damage roll when attacking with a melee weapon such as a mace, a battleaxe or a javelin.

So yes, you still get your ability modifier to the attack roll.